# ¿ Como colocar unos botones de avance y retoceso a los costador de un slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo el siguiente slider, pero no le puedo colocar unos botones a los costados de avance y retroceso para que tenga mas precisión.

```
$("#mySlider").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        min: 10000,
        max: 300000,
        step: 500

});
```

No se si exista alguna propiedad para ponerle dichos botones por lo cual he buscado en varias paginas y no he econtrado nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tal cual no existe una propiedad para agregar los botones, pero los puedes agregar manualmente y mediante el método [value](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-values) puedes cambiar el valor de tu slider, por ejemplo:

```
var valorSlider = $("#mySlider").slider("value"); //Obtenemos el valor del slider
$("#mySlider").slider("value", valorSlider+5000); //A el valor obtenido le sumamos cierta cantidad
```

El código anterior funciona para incrementar el valor, puedes hacer lo mismo para reducir el valor, solo tienes que cambiar el signo.

El código HTML sería, añadí un contenedor para el slider:

```
<button id="agregar">+</button>
<div class="container">
 <div id="mySlider"></div>
</div>
<button id="restar">-</button>
```

Los estilos, le tienes que dar un ancho al slider y poner los elementos inline-block:

```
button{
  display: inline-block;
}

.container{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

El código JS sería:

```
$("#mySlider").slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 0,
      min: 10000,
      max: 300000,
      step: 500
});

$('#agregar').click(function(){
  var valorSlider = $("#mySlider").slider("value");
  $("#mySlider").slider("value", valorSlider+5000);
});

$('#restar').click(function(){
  var valorSlider = $("#mySlider").slider("value");
  $("#mySlider").slider("value", valorSlider-5000);
});
```

[Aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/checosele/byj9udaz/) te dejo un ejemplo en fiddle.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono de maravilla. Problema resuelto.

Comment: Que bueno que te funcionó, te invito a leer este enlace [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), buen día.